# Django App Not Writing Any Records to DB

Tags: python, django

I'm using this script https://github.com/jsfenfen/990-xml-database. This script loops through a large volume of XML files, then writes the contents to a database. I run the command

> $ python manage.py load_filings 2017

And the script immediately says it's completed, as in the photo below:
[image]

I know that the database connection works properly, because it's creating the 180 or so tables in the database. However, all tables are blank.

One other note: The GitHub repo says "This is Django 2, so only python3 is supported." My version is Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit).

Given that there's no error message, what can I post here or research to better identify the problem? (Complete Python/Django newbie)

Comment: Maybe the script doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This problem had to do with a bug related to how microsoft programs encode utf-8; specifically, for files beginning with the \ufeff BOM on windows it's safer to use 'utf-8-sig' rather than 'utf-8'. This particular issue is fixed in the upstream library, [irsx](https://github.com/jsfenfen/990-xml-reader), in v 0.2.3. You can update with something like `$pip install --upgrade irsx`.

This software's not been tested on windows, but please report any bugs you encounter. In general if you include the complete verbatim script output its easier to debug.